# Concurrencia en Javascript: ¿Cómo detengo una función? (Concurrent.Thread)

Tags: javascript, jquery, hilos

tengo un problema al hacer solicitudes *XMLHttpRequest*, la siguiente función comprueba si un enlace .m3u8 existe:

```
    function disponible(ch,senial) {
    var url = ch[senial].url;//aquí está la url con enlace m3u8 a verificar si existe
    try{
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('HEAD', url, false);
        http.send();
        document.getElementById("noDisponible").innerHTML = (http.status!=404?"":"ERROR: Por el momento, no disponible");
    }catch(err){
        document.getElementById("noDisponible").innerHTML = "No disponible";
    }
    setTimeout(disponible(ch,senial), 300);
}
```

La función anterior puede demorar en ejecutar, por lo que el navegador queda bloqueado imposibilitando ejecutar el resto de las funciones del sitio en el que está. Estoy probando con *Concurrent.Thread*, pero  no me está quedando ya que si la función de arriba demora, bloquea el navegador esperando a que termine. Esta es la forma en la que creo un nuevo thread:

> Concurrent.Thread.create(disponible, ch,senial);

Pareciera  que lo hace, pero en la práctica no me solucionó el problema. También probé agregar esta línea para ver si al menos detenía  la función anterior después de cierto período de tiempo:

> setTimeout(disponible(ch,senial), 300);

pero no hay  caso.

No puse más código porque el programa es muy grande, pero si hace falta para comprender el problema pongo más.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Multithreading en javascript? ¿Seguro? ¿Quizás te refieres a los workers?

Comment: Perdón, me faltó agregar la libería  que utilicé, en realidad creo que simula un Multithreading